# How can I format a decimal without separators and without decimals?

Tags: c#

How can I format a decimal to be converted to a string without group separators and without decimals?

For eg: "1,234.56" should be displayed as "1234".

Comment: Can you just cast to `int` first?

Comment: (Getting it to display as 1235, i.e. rounding up, is reasonably easy. Truncating *just in the format string* isn't.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This almost works, but rounds up:

```
Decimal d = 1234.56M;
string s = string.Format("{0:0}", d);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Outputs: `1235`

As @Jon Skeet suggested, you could cast to an integer type (assuming it was large enough to hold your largest decimal value):

```
Decimal d = 1234.56M;
string s = string.Format("{0}", (long)d);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Outputs: `1234`

Demo: http://ideone.com/U4dcZD

Comment: Or cast to a `BigInteger` if the `long` is too small (doubtful, but hey! You never know!)

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand why you cant just use a cast. I think an Int will not show comma (,). But anyways, this should do the trick:

```
        float n = 1234.78f;
        int i = (int)n;
        String str = i.ToString();
        while (str.IndexOf(",",0) >= 0 )
            str = str.Remove(str.IndexOf(",", 0), 1);
```